# folder gets created but no files in it

Tags: python, flask, vlc

I have a digital ocean droplet which has a linux os on it. On this vm I have a flask webserver and in the `__init__.py` script I have these two functions:

```
@app.route('/ds')
def ds():
    fp = "/home/ds/gabo/"
    pre = 'das_'
    req_value = create_vlc_command(pre, fp)
    os.system(req_value)
    return req_value

def create_vlc_command(pre_fn, full_path):
    pre_sc_path = '--scene-path='
    file_name = pre_fn + get_date_time()
    vid_settings = ("--rate=1 --video-filter=scene "
                   "--vout=dummy --run-time=3 "
                   "--scene-format=png --scene-ratio=24 "
                   "--scene-prefix=") + file_name
    scene_path = pre_sc_path + full_path
    req_value = ("vlc {arg_name} {vid_settings} {scene_path} "
                 "{quit}").format(arg_name="htttp:examplexxx.com",
                vid_settings=vid_settings, scene_path=scene_path,
                quit='vlc://quit')  
    return req_value
```

When I hit ctrl + r on the *droplet-ip*/ds i can see the req_value and the folder gets created on the vm but I don't see any pictures in that folder. But when I run the req_value later in the terminal, the pictures get created.

The command on the page:

```
vlc http://exampleamplexxx.com/dsa.m3u8 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --run-time=3 --scene-format=png --scene-ratio=24 --scene-prefix=pi_pic_lc_2017_12_09_15_58_30 --scene-path=/home/ds/gabo/ vlc://quit
```

Is something wrong with the os.system or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the file name really is `__init_.py` you should change it to `__init__.py`(add another underscore at the end)?

Comment: but then it gets formated, is there an escape character? thanks

Comment: use char ` ("tick" on key with ~ , above key `Tab`) to escape text `__init__`

Comment: done, thx......